# speech to text software

Tags: windows, linux, speech-to-text

I have several .amr audio files containing lectures. I want to transcribe them to text. What is the best software available for achieving this?

i am working on windows, linux.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen people have great and poor success with [Dragon Naturally Speaking](http://www.nuance.com/naturallyspeaking/). Since this program is fine tuned to one voice (and requires you to train the software), it's not really good to use on someone else's voice or a recording with different people talking.

Those who had a good experience with this wanted to transcribe interviews they had done, so they had a mix of their own voice (good) with someone else's. What they did was replay the interviews in their headsets and dictate over into the microphone what they were hearing. This way the program only had to deal with one voice.

Answer (score 0):

IBM ViaVoice:
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/pervasive/embedded_viavoice/

Adarsh